# Facebook Graph API encoding - Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am going around in circles and tried so many different ways so I guess my core understanding is wrong.  I would be grateful for help in understanding my encoding/decoding issues.

```
import urllib2

result = urllib2.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/163146530455639")
rawdata = result.read().decode('utf-8')

print "HEADER: " + str(result.info())

print "I want this to work ", rawdata.find('http://www.facebook.com')
print "I dont want this to work ", rawdata.find('http:\/\/www.facebook.com')
```

I guess what im getting isnt utf-8 even though the header seems to say it is.  Or as a newbie to Python im doing something dumb. :(

Thanks for any help,

Phil

Comment: I did try:
    chardet.detect(rawdata)
    {'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}

Answer (score 1):

You're getting JSON back from Facebook, so the easiest thing to do is use the built in `json` module to decode it (provided you're using Python 2.6+, otherwise you'll have to install).

```
import json
import urllib2

result = urllib2.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/163146530455639")
rawdata = result.read()
jsondata = json.load(rawdata)

print jsondata['link']
```

gives you:

```
u'http://www.facebook.com/GrosvenorCafe'
```